# Select all children that match a union of particular nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

Suppose I have this xml node:

```
<a>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
    <d></d>
</a>
```

I want to select all children of a particular node, that contains a list of XPATH's I have with me.

e.g. 
/a/*[.=/a/b | .=/a/d]

should select only `<b> and <d>` nodes, but it selects all nodes: `<b>,<c>,<d>`

How can I do this?

> Complete Details:

```
<BooksInfo>
    <Publisher Repeat="true">
        <PublisherName/>
        <Author Repeat="true">
            <AuthorName/>
            <Book Repeat="true">
                <BookName/>
                <Chapter Repeat="true"/>
                <Preface/>
                <Contents/>
            </Book>
            <Magazine>
                <MagazineName/>
                <Chapter Repeat="true"/>
                <Title/>
            </Magazine>
        </Author>
    </Publisher>
</BooksInfo>
```

My application is based on Visual Studio Tools For Office - Content Controls. What my application does is, suppose I drop book/chapter element on my word document and then I apply a Repeating Section Content Control around it. Now I want to apply an XmlMapping for this content control and want to show the user a dialog box where he can select the XmlNode from where to repeat the Chapter elements.

Now, this chapter can be from either `<Magazine> or <book>` nodes, but the user has dropped the `<book>/chapter` on the document and so, the popup window should show as choices - only the chapter from the book element and not the magazine element.

I have a tree view in WPF, that's based on the HierarchicalDataTemplate and I set the ItemsSource to an XPath expression that should do just this.

And this is the expression that I have:
[Besides the above condition, it should show only nodes with "Repeat='true'" or nodes that have descendants with "Repeat='true'"

Expression:

```
./*[(@Repeat="true" or .//*[@Repeat="true"]) and ({0})]
```

The {0} part, I add dynamically, by inserting those elements that have been dropped on the document.

an instance of this XPath for above scenario is:

```
./*[(@Repeat="true" or .//*[@Repeat="true"]) and (self::Chapter)]
```

But this will show following choices in the popup tree view:

```
BooksInfo
    - Publisher
        - Author
            - Book
                - Chapter
            - Magazine
                - Chapter
```

The last Magazine/Chapter can only be removed, when I compare the current node with the complete XPath rather than just the name of the node, like this:

```
./*[(@Repeat="true" or .//*[@Repeat="true"]) and (self::/BooksInfo/Publisher/Author/Magazine/Chapter)]
```

Comment: The path expressions you show are not valid expressions, things like `./[` are not allowed. Apart from that, I still don't understand the scenario. You'd like to keep nodes where `@Repeat = "true"` or that have descendants where `@Repeat = "true"` - why does the `Magazine` part need to be removed then?

Comment: (Please ignore the first part of my comment, that was just due to formatting.)

Comment: Magazine part needs to be removed, because the user needs to take only the book part and leave out the Magazie part. Because, only 'chapter' node of 'book' was taken from the tree view and dropped on document and 'chapter' node of 'magazine' was not taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your attempted expression is that `=` is not doing what you think it is doing. You assume that `=` works like an `is` operator, testing node identity. But in fact, an expression like

```
. = /a/d
```

tests whether the **string value** of the context node is equal to the string value of the element the path on the right side evaluates to.

The expression above evaluates to a **boolean** value, and thus

```
 .=/a/b | .=/a/d
```

contains two boolean values, combined with `union`.

If you only want to select `b` and `d` elements, use

```
 /a/*[self::b or self::d]
```

which will return (individual results separated by `-------`):

```
<b/>
-----------------------
<d/>
```

Besides, if you have a set of XPath expressions, why not simply evaluate *those*, separated by the union?

```
/a/d | /a/b
```

the result set being the same.

Comment: In the real project, I have a different situation and it is a very big XPATH expression created dynamically. But, if I can test for complete XPATH expression inside like /a/*[self::/a/b or self::/a/d], then it will solve my problem. Something like that is possible?

Comment: I can't simply evaluate complete XPATH expression, because I already know that they are there in the document. But what I need is to check whether the current element being looked is equal to that node or not.

Comment: @teenup What do you mean by "equal"? Node identity? Same textual content? _Why_ do you need to make this check? Evaluating the expressions you already have will yield the same results, what's the difference?

Comment: By equal, I don't  mean same textual content, I mean xpath for the currently evaluated node i.e. (.) should be equal to the xpath expression I provide. Although, I can pass the name only like you have shown using self::b, but in this case, if ther is another node named b somewhere else in the other branch of xml, than that branch will also be included in the result. Because, I am rendering a tree view and parsing the entire tree, and every element in the xml, goes through this selection AnyNode/*[Predicate]

Comment: @teenup Selecting nodes that share identity with a (i.e. are the same) node obtained by evaluating your path expressions is **the same** as simply evaluating them.

Comment: I need to reframe my question in more detail to explain to you what I want.  You have already provided me half solution. I will add more details in my quesiton. It will take an hour.

Comment: I have updated the question by adding more details to clear the situation why I need to equate the node identity.

Comment: @Mathis Do you think it can be done. If not, please comment, I will accept your answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @teenup Unfortunately, I'm still not sure what you need. But I'll give it another try, will comment on the question in a moment.

Comment: I have resolved this and posted an answer. As you helped me in right direction, I will mark your's as answer. Thanks.

Comment: @teenup I'm glad you found the answer yourself, +1!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it using the following expression:

./*[descendant-or-self::node()[@Repeat="true"] and ({0})]

As I wanted to compare full xpath of the element in {0} part of expression above. I did it as follows:

e.g. If I need to select the book/chapter rather than both the Chapters from Book and Magazine, I will do following:

descendant-or-self::Chapter/parent::book/parent::Author/....SoOn